# Jest - how can I expect.anything() or null?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

`expect.anything()` does not work for `null` or undefined.
Is there anyway I can include a check for null or expect.anything() in below code?
Here, `auth` can be `anything` or `null`.

```
const transactionsListResponseKey = {
  id: expect.anything(),
  amount: expect.anything(),
  currency: expect.anything(),
  auth: expect.anything()
}
```

Comment: If you don't care about the value for a key, why not use e.g. objectMatching?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [.toBeOneOf([members])](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended#tobeoneofmembers) assertion API of [jest-extended](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-extended) combined with `expect.anything()`

> Use `.toBeOneOf` when checking if a value is a member of a given Array.

```
import 'jest-extended';

describe('69198224', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const auth1 = 'a';
    const auth2 = null;
    const auth3 = 1;
    const auth4 = {};
    const auth5 = undefined;
    const auth6 = [];
    const auth7 = () => {};
    expect(auth1).toBeOneOf([null, expect.anything()]); // pass
    expect(auth2).toBeOneOf([null, expect.anything()]); // pass
    expect(auth3).toBeOneOf([null, expect.anything()]); // pass
    expect(auth4).toBeOneOf([null, expect.anything()]); // pass
    expect(auth6).toBeOneOf([null, expect.anything()]); // pass
    expect(auth7).toBeOneOf([null, expect.anything()]); // pass

    expect(auth5).toBeOneOf([null, expect.anything()]); // fail
  });
});
```